# Is there any free backup solution for Vmware VMs?

Tags: software-development, virtual-machine, virtualization

My client has 10 virtual machines at present,and he want to test a suitable free backup solution for backing up his Vmware environment before make a final decision.

Comment: Do you want to make backups from within the guests or from within the host(s)? What is your host OS? your guest OSes?

Comment: from guests with linux

Comment: you can try *deja-dup* if the guests have Gnome installed (unlikely if they are servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to test vinchin free edition which can support Vmware environment. And besides it also has some features that may cover your demands like CBT,data compression,incremental backup and differential backup and so on.

Comment: Vinchin backup software support agentless backup? and what kind of type does your backup solution support as a repository?

Comment: Thanks for your asking. vinchin support agentless backup.only need to install a small plug-in on your hypervisor layer. then you could backup unlimited VMs.

Comment: and we support partition, local disk, LVM, FC,ISCSI,NFS,CIFS

Comment: hope my answer could help you